# Oracle insert into table2 then delete from table1, exception if fail

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

creating a procedure that will insert the data from my table1 into my table2 and delete it after insert, or in case the table2 has reached its limit then i will create a new backup table.

I have two tables `sii_bck_cfg_tab` and `sii_bck_tab`

On `cfg_tab` i have a list of table_names with a couple of columns `(id,name_tab, prefix_tab, created_on , keep_days, max_rows_bck)`
prefix_tab- where i get the prefix when i need to create a new backup table
keep_days- the number of days i want to keep the tables data
max_rows- the number of rows ill add to the backup table before i create a new one.

on my `bck_tab` i have the following columns `(id, tab_name, id_cfg_bck, created_on, close_dt)` 
tab_name-name of the created backup table
id_cfg_bck- FK from cfg_bck
close_dt- the date when the backup table reaches its limit and is "closed"

```
enter code here
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LIMPAR_TAB_proc 
IS

stmt VARCHAR2(1000);
stmt_ins_bck VARCHAR2(1000);

n_tab sii_bck_cfg_tab.nome_tab%type;
prefix sii_bck_cfg_tab.pref_tab_bck%type;
max_reg sii_bck_cfg_tab.max_reg_bck%type;
id_fk sii_bck_cfg_tab.id_bck_cfg_tab%type;
dt_criado sii_bck_cfg_tab.criado_em%TYPE;  

id_fk2 sii_bck_tab.id_bck_cfg_tab%type;
dt_fec sii_bck_tab.dt_fecho%TYPE;
n_tab2 sii_bck_tab.nome_tab%type;
stmt_ins VARCHAR2(500);
id_seq VARCHAR2(500);
num_rows VARCHAR2(500);
stmt_up VARCHAR2(500);
stmt_del VARCHAR2(500);

CURSOR c1 IS
SELECT ID_BCK_CFG_TAB,Nome_tab, pref_tab_bck, max_reg_bck, criado_em FROM sii_bck_cfg_tab WHERE desativado_em IS NULL OR desativado_em<=SYSDATE AND n_dias_reten>0 ORDER BY criado_em; 

CURSOR c2 IS 
SELECT sii_bck_tab.ID_BCK_CFG_TAB , sii_bck_tab.nome_tab from sii_bck_tab,sii_bck_cfg_tab WHERE sii_bck_cfg_tab.id_bck_cfg_tab=sii_bck_tab.id_bck_cfg_tab and dt_fecho is NULL;

BEGIN                                  

OPEN c1;
LOOP
--inserir os registos que cumprem a restrição da data e dos dias de retenção
FETCH c1 INTO id_fk,n_tab,prefix,max_reg, dt_criado;
EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Nome Tabela c1 = ' || id_fk ||' '|| n_tab ||' '|| prefix ||' '|| max_reg); 


    OPEN c2;
      LOOP

         FETCH c2 INTO id_fk2, n_tab2;
        --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('chave aqui c2= ' || id_fk2 || n_tab2);

         --registos de tabelas que não estão fechadas           
         IF c2%FOUND AND id_fk=id_fk2 THEN
         BEGIN
         SAVEPOINT start_transaction;
           stmt_ins:= 'INSERT all into ' || n_tab2 || ' SELECT * FROM ' || n_tab || ' where ' || dt_criado || '<' || SYSDATE;
           --falta verificar se foi bem sucedido e apagar da original

        -- EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt_ins;
                        dbms_output.put_line('value '||SQL%ROWCOUNT);
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stmt_ins);

         siima_logs_bck.INSE_LOG(1,'TESTE INSERIR','INS_LOGS','2', 'testes insert log');
        EXCEPTION 
        WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
          ROLLBACK TO start_transaction; 

        END; 
         stmt_del:= 'DELETE FROM ' || n_tab || ' WHERE (SELECT *
         FROM ' || n_tab2 || ' WHERE criado_em' ||'<'|| sysdate ;

         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stmt_del);
         siima_logs_bck.INSE_LOG(1,'TESTE ELIMINAR','INS_LOGS','2', 'testes delete log');
         ELSE IF c2%NOTFOUND THEN 
           stmt:= 'create table ' || prefix || SII_BCK_TAB_ID_SEQ.nextval || 
           ' AS SELECT * FROM '|| n_tab || ' WHERE 1=0';
         --  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stmt);
         --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
           id_seq:= prefix||SII_BCK_TAB_ID_SEQ.CURRVAL;
         -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(id_seq); 
           stmt_ins_bck:= 'insert into sii_bck_tab(nome_tab,id_bck_cfg_tab) VALUES ' || '(' || id_seq || ',' || id_fk || ')';
         --  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stmt_ins_bck);
           --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt_ins_bck; 

           EXIT WHEN c2%NOTFOUND;           
         END IF;    
         END IF;  
                       --vefificar numero de registos e update
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT Count (*) from ' ||n_tab INTO num_rows;
       --  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(num_rows);

         IF num_rows>max_reg THEN             
         stmt_up:='update ' || n_tab ||  ' set ' || dt_fec || '=' || sysdate;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stmt_up);
         --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt_up;

         END IF;

      END LOOP;
    CLOSE c2;
END LOOP;
CLOSE c1;
end;
```

what im having trouble at the moment is to insert into a dynamic table and then delete if i have successfully inserted into the backup table.

```
stmt_ins:= 'INSERT all into ' || n_tab2 || ' SELECT * FROM ' || n_tab || ' where ' || dt_criado || '<' || SYSDATE;
```

--this stmt works without the where clause, but i need it to work so i can filter the data by date.

i want to make sure i have inserted my data correctly into my backup table and then delete from my main table.

```
stmt_del:= 'DELETE FROM ' || n_tab || ' WHERE (SELECT *
             FROM ' || n_tab2 || ' WHERE criado_em' ||'<'|| sysdate ;
```

on my delete statemente i have the same problem with the `criado_em` column.

This is a procedure that will run in a job and pass data from main table onto backup tables daily, and keep a certain amount of data on the main table(like for example last 30 days)

Thank you for any help

Comment: SO what is the specific error, and where?

Comment: Do you have to do it like this? Can you not use partitions? (They would be easier to maintain, as you can just drop/exchange partitions as necessary.)

Comment: the error is on my insert, i cant use the where clause. 
Sadly i cant use partitions :(

Comment: the error i get is ORA-00920 invalid operator, i would also like to verify if i all my data was inserted before i delete it from my original table

Answer (score 0):

> this stmt works without the where clause

That could be because when you concatenate the strings they are converted implicitly and your where condition fails at run time. Try the `USING` clause with bind variables.

```
stmt_ins:= 'INSERT  INTO ' || n_tab2 || ' SELECT * FROM ' || n_tab || ' where ' || dt_criado || ' < :dt ' ;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt_ins USING SYSDATE;
```

Comment: how would i declare :dt?

Comment: @Sapo121 : No declaration needed for `:dt`

Comment: keeps giving me the same error, so i thought i had to do some declaration

Comment: @Sapo121 : Can you display the query?

Comment: this is the output without the execute part using sysdate, 

INSERT into HS_TESTES_2 SELECT * FROM sii_bck_logs.HS_TESTES where 18.10.30 < :dt

Comment: @Sapo121 : So, there's your problem. `dt_criado` contains the actual date instead of the column name.There's something wrong in your logic

Comment: but i want dt_criado to have that date, i want to insert all the data where dt_criado is < then sysdate

Comment: @Sapo121 :  It's not comparing the column dt_criado, it's using the value of `dt_criado` and doing the comparison which won't work anyway. It's like doing `select * from t where 1 < 2` in which the outcome of the actual comparison means nothing for any column in the table and if it's true all rows will be returned,0 otherwise.  You have to get the column name of the table in that variable for it to work.

Comment: I thought that was what i was doing when i fetch with the cursors, any tips on the best way to do that?