# obtaining columns dynamically from dynamic table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

i have a two tables that i need to access one using cursor c1 and the other using cursor c2 , they both store columns containing table names that i need to access to perform operations like insert or delete.

```
CURSOR c1 IS
      SELECT ID_BCK_CFG_TAB,
             Nome_tab,
             pref_tab_bck,
             max_reg_bck,
             criado_em
        FROM sii_bck_cfg_tab
       WHERE desativado_em IS NULL 
          OR desativado_em<=SYSDATE
         AND n_dias_reten>0
    ORDER BY criado_em; 

CURSOR c2 IS 
    SELECT sii_bck_tab.ID_BCK_CFG_TAB,
           sii_bck_tab.nome_tab
      FROM sii_bck_tab,
           sii_bck_cfg_tab
     WHERE sii_bck_cfg_tab.id_bck_cfg_tab = sii_bck_tab.id_bck_cfg_tab
       AND dt_fecho is NULL;
```

when i loop through them i need to insert and delete certain rows, how can i dynamically get certain columns like for example criado_em from my cursor c1.

i need to perform operations like

```
stmt_ins:= 'INSERT into ' || n_tab2 || ' SELECT * FROM ' || n_tab || ' where ''' || dt_criado  || '< :dt';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt_ins USING sysdate;
```

but i cant because i dont know how to return the variable dt_criado as a column value of criado_em from the dynamic table im consulting.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: follow up from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53156179/oracle-insert-into-table2-then-delete-from-table1-exception-if-fail/53156976?noredirect=1#comment93205486_53156976

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
open c1;

loop
    fetch c1 into tmp; -- get current row
    exit when c1%notfound; -- check if more rows exist

    IF tmp.myDateCol >= SYSDATE THEN 
        execute immediate 'INSERT INTO ' || tmp.colname  || ' VALUES (1,2)';
    END IF;
end loop;
```

Comment: thats not what im looking for, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53156179/oracle-insert-into-table2-then-delete-from-table1-exception-if-fail

i need to filter my insert by date, but i cant access my criado_em from that table that is listed on c1.

Comment: i tried to show you how to access a specific column from your cursor. edited the example: Checks a date-column in an if-clause. Inserts with dynamic sql into a table from another column of your cursor. The key is `FETCH c1 INTO tmp`. `tmp` works like a variable for you.